# How to show Push notifications when app is closed similar to facebook and whatsapp

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

The messages than would be shows will not be send from a server, this would be created for same app, for example if user has not enter in 3 day (72 hours) to app I want to show an "PUSH NOTIFICATION" showing "hey enter to app to see the last games added".

So this message would be shows ever happens 72 hours users not enter to app
I said similar to facebook and whatsapp because you dont have the app open (may be in background or with a intenteservice or service)

But I dont know if it is a good Idea to have a service running "always"

Comment: Have a look at `AlarmManager`, `BroadcastReceiver` and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many apps that have services constantly running. If you go into your app manager on your phone you can see that. There isn't a problem with this as long as you aren't doing constant processing of data. That would kill the battery.

I think you could use a Service in addition to the AlarmManager to do this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html